Jupiter Swap API
I need help with the Jupiter Swap API. I'm stuck on a problem. I’m using the Jupiter Swap API to swap tokens, but I want to swap WSOL instead of SOL. I set the wrapUnwrapSOL option to true, but I’m still facing an issue. How can I correctly set this up?
 const swapTransaction = await (
            await fetch("https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/swap", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    quoteResponse,
                    userPublicKey: userWallet.payer.publicKey.toString(),
                    wrapUnwrapSOL: true,
                    prioritizationFeeLamports: priorityFee,
                    dynamicComputeUnitLimit: true,
                }),
            })
        ).json();


there is no error. When I swap ABC to WSOL. it returned me SOL and add SOL insto my wallet instead of WSOL. I want that WSOL will add

what if you wrap the sol after the swap transaction? Is that a viable option for you?

It will take separate gas fee to swap

if tx size limit isn';t reached you could bundle the  ix's into one.
